# ng-options with multiselect inside ng-repeat is throwing console error in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

My code will be go like this in UI

```
<div class="row" ng-show="ab.row.process=='cks'" ng-repeat="field in ab.getFields">

    <div  ng-show="ab.fieldType[field]=='multi-select'">
            <!--         <select class="md-selectbox" multiple="true"
                        ng-model="ab.list[field]"                           
                        ng-change="os.setValue(ab.list,ab.list[field], field)">
                        <option ng-repeat="opt in ab.options[field] track by $index">{{opt}}</option>
                    </select> -->
                    <select class="md-selectbox" multiple dynamic-name="field"
                        ng-model="ab.list[field]"
                        ng-required= "field == 'Apple'"
                        ng-change="ab.setValue(ab.list,ab.list[field], field)" 
                        ng-options="opt for opt in ab.options[field]">
                    </select>
                </div>

</div>
```

While i am using the Commented select options i am not able to render the values in IE. IT works fine in chrome and FF. When i am using the second select option which is enabled now is working fine in both. But it throws console error in IE.
Console error it throwing are:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
>
> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Comment: please also post you js code

Comment: <div class="row" ng-show="ab.getRow.process =='pnk'" ng-repeat="field in ab.getAllProcess">
      <select class="md-selectbox" multiple="true" 
        ng-model="ab.list[field]"
        ng-required= "field == 'apple'"
        ng-change="ab.setValue(ab.list,ab.list[field], field)" 
        ng-options="opt for opt in ab.options[field]" multiselect-dropdown>
      </select>
</div>

Comment: commented select will be here   :                        <!--<select class="md-selectbox" multiple="true"
        ng-model="ab.list[field]"        
        ng-change="ab.setValue(ab.list,ab.list[field], field)">
                <option ng-repeat="opt in ab.options[field] track by $index">{{opt}}</option>
      </select> -->

Comment: please update your question qith your `JavaScript` code...